# Enter doesn't always generate a LF

Tags: html

I have a div I've set up with contentEditable = "TRUE". When I enter text into the div an Enter at the end of a line always generate a CR but not always a LF. The times it doesn't generate a LF, a LF is generate automatically if I type something.  If I display something else on the screen that seems to drop into a mode where then both CR and LF are generated  by an  Enter in my editable div. Does anyone know what this could be?

Thanks.

Comment: what is CR? what is LF?

Comment: CR = Carriage Return.  LF = Line Feed.

Comment: @RyonnSan, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Comment: What browser is this happening under? Do you have a test case that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: It only happens with Firefox.  If I set up a jsfiddle with Firefox, though, it works ok. So it's only Firefox and it's only with my environment.

Comment: How did you deduce that the internal representation is CR?

Comment: I say "CR" because I see the cursor going to the beginning of the line. So the monitor itself must be getting a CR (and no LF since cursor doesn't skip down one line).  If you look at the HTML generated, though,  you can see that the browser is inserting a <br>.